# WPF showing a user control in dialog using reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, prism

Currently, i have the following code inside a Switch / Case. This codes works fine for me, but I looking for a solution on how I can do this using reflection. Otherwise, I have to repeat the following code 70 times.

```
var popupViewModel = new NetworkNameDescriptorViewModel(_eventAggregator)
{
    DescriptorContext = new DescriptorModel {
        Hex = obj.Hex,
        Tag = obj.Tag,
        Length = obj.Length,
        Name = obj.Name
    }
};
var popupView =_container.Resolve<NetworkNameDescriptor.NetworkNameDescriptor>();
popupView.DataContext = popupViewModel;

Window window = new Window()
{
    Title = "Network name descriptor",
    Content = popupView
};
window.Show();
```

Comment: Are you using unity (I see eventAggregator)? Is the type known at compile type (could you call it using Show<T> for example)? Is the view model always the same ?

Comment: Yes, I'm showing Prism with UnityBootstrapper

Comment: That is the problem, the ViewModel is not always the same; I have 70 ViewModels. That's why I'm looking for a more dynamic solution

Comment: What part of the code are you looking to make "more dynamic"?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, can automatically resolve Views and ViewModels for them (if they are registered in the UnityContainer.

So I think, you should:
1) add to each view this attached property.

```
mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

By default PRISM can resolve ViewModel for View, but they should have same name ViewA and ViewAViewModel, and be in appropriate folders (Views for views, and ViewModels for view models)

2) For collecting views I've used Attribute, which I've applied to each view, also I've used it for registering view in some PrismRegions. (You can delete this properties. I'm using them to create View Based Navigation )

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RegionRegistrationAttribute: Attribute 
{
    public RegionRegistrationAttribute()
    {

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of region where view will be registred
    /// </summary>
    public String InjectionRegionName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is name of registartion in 
    /// </summary>
    public String RegistrationName { get; set; }
}
```

3) And then apply this attribute for views

```
 [RegionRegistration(InjectionRegionName = RegionNames.ContentRegion, RegistrationName = ViewNames.MainView )]
public partial class MainView : Window
{

//some code

}
```

4) As views in my solution are separated by modules so i should collect and register views per modules. For this I've created simple loader, which loads views from calling assembly (Its module in my case) (you can use Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); to get right assembly)

```
        public void CollectAndRegisterViews()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var viewNamespace = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{_defaultAssemblyFolder}";

        var types = from type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.Namespace==viewNamespace)
                    where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(RegionRegistrationAttribute))
                    select type;

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"\t>>Registering View by type{type.FullName}");

            var attribute = type.GetCustomAttributes<RegionRegistrationAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(attribute.InjectionRegionName, type);

           _container.RegisterType(typeof(object), type, attribute.RegistrationName);
        }
    }
```

5)And then, if you did everything right in your switch you will have smth like this:

```
  _container.Resolve<MainView>().Show()
```

And then Prism will resolve automatically ViewModel for your MainView.

Comment: What is in  RegisterViewInUnityContainerAndRegionManager? Thanks

Comment: fixed, Its method for registering in unity container